# Is there a real file for stream i/o in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, stream

I confused in concept of `i/o stream` in the `linux`.
There is 3 types of stream: standard input. standard output and standard error.
Is there a real file in the ram or hard disk for `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`?
For example: kernel writes all keyboard inputs to a `stdin` file? and then bash(for example) read this file?
And if this true, that's mean any software can read this file in any time?

Comment: They're drivers caracters, not really a file as you think. The easiest example is /dev/null, the driver read the character and that all, when the reader as read a character you can't not read it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every process has (at least initially) the standard stdin/stdout/stderr file handles opened for it. Every process also has a representation in /proc, which is a virtual file system created by the kernel to access all kinds of stuff about the processes. So...

```
marc@panic:~$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4367 pts/0    00:00:00 bash     <--- my bash process
 4394 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
marc@panic:~$ cd /proc/4367/fd   <---my bash processes's /proc file descriptors
marc@panic:/proc/4367/fd$ ls -l
total 0
lrwx------ 1 marc marc 64 Nov 17 11:17 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 marc marc 64 Nov 17 11:17 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 marc marc 64 Nov 17 11:17 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 marc marc 64 Nov 17 11:18 255 -> /dev/pts/0
```

files `0`, `1`, `2` correspond to stdin, stdout, stderr, and they're simply symlinks to the particular pseudo terminal my login session is using.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call these *real files*, but:

You can use `/dev/stdout` etc on Linux.